# How to highlight the extra white spaces with red background in sublime3

Tags: ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed a plugin through Package Control, that highlight the extra whitespaces with red background color. I loved it! However, I reinstalled the sublime3 and its gone. The only trace I still remember that its somehow deal with I installed the DocBlockr, but now I went to their git page, I do not see any related function.

I am really frustrated and wonder how can I find this plugin or somewhat change sublime3 setting to achieve it? Because right now I am using

> "draw_white_space": "all"

which is really horrible on the eye with all the lines and dots in between.

Thanks

Comment: try searching google and [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search)

Comment: @MattDMo Trust me, I did, I can't find the plugin that did that! All the related keywords I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this one ? [TrailingSpaces](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TrailingSpaces)

Comment: Thank YOU! That's exactly the one. I never thought that was though, since I did not see any image relate to it on its git :D